# Arredondar valor JSON

Tags: javascript, json, react

Em meu codigo, recebo um JSON com um valor (Exemplo: 6647), e gostaria de arredondar o mesmo para apenas 1 casa decimal.

No codigo, pego o conteudo do JSOn pela chamada:

```
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
                   <div className="col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
                   <div className = "row">
                       <div className = "info-box">
                           <span className = "info-box-icon logo-View">
                           <i className = "fa fa-tasks"> </i> </span>
                           <div className = "info-box-content">
                                 <span className = "info-box-number">{this.state.data.pageViews}</span>
                                 <span className = "info-box-text"> Page Views </span>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div></div>
            </div>

    );
  }
```

E a classe:

```
 componentDidMount(){
        let URL = 'algumaURL'
           fetch(URL)
           .then(function(response) {
              let data = response.json()
              return data;
           })
           .then((json) => {
              console.log('parsed json', json)
              this.setState({data : json});
           })
           .catch(function(ex) {
              console.log('parsing failed', ex)
           })
  }
```

**JSON:**

```
{"pageViews":13184}
```

**Valor de pageViews é aleatori a cada refresh da pagina.**

Comment: Quantas casas decimais por padrão, duas `66,47` ou três `6,647`?

Comment: Arredondar para 1 casa decimal, 6,647 -> 6,6

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função JS [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

> O método **toFixed()** formata um número utilizando notação de ponto fixo.
>
> **Sintaxe:** numObj.toFixed([dígitos])

**Exemplo:**

```js
var num = 6.647; 
//O parâmetro da função é o número de casas decimais.
var numeroFormatado = num.toFixed(1);

console.log(numeroFormatado);
/* OBS.:
Se a casa consecutiva a informada no parâmetro
For superior ou igual a 5 o valor será arrendoado para cima.
*/
```

Comment: No meu JSON, o numero recebido nao tem separação por pontos de virgulas (Exemplo: 66557), e se eu aplicar seu codigo, recebo esse erro:   
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined

Comment: Tem certeza que o valor recebido é do tipo número? Porque se for número e não tem separação por vírgulas, não é decimal. É inteiro, portanto, não tem como arrendondar. Coloque o modelo do JSON recebido na sua pergunta para entendermos melhor o problema. O número de casas decimais deste número é padrão?

Comment: adicionado o json recebido

Comment: Vi o json e o valor recebido é inteiro, então sua questão não faz sentido com um valor inteiro.